# what is the difference between authToken and access token

Tags: angular, facebook, access-token, google-signin, facebook-access-token

I am trying to integrate google signin in my application(using Angular 4) using [that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-social-login)

and I am getting a `SocialUser` that contains multiple fields like

```
name
id
email
.
.
.
authToken
```

my question is `what is authToken,and how I can get the access token of a Socialuser ?`.

**Note**: I think that the authToken format is different to Google access token format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I GOT IT

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534806/angular-how-can-i-get-google-access-token/52551217#52551217)

> **------------------------>the token and authtoken are differents**