# Angular : how can I get Google access token

Tags: angular, access-token, google-signin, illegalargumentexception, auth-token

I am trying to get Access token using Angular 4.
When the user logIn using Google I get the following Data.

```
authToken // *
id
email
.
.
.
name
```

- I think that the variable `authToken` is not the `access token` because when I try to verify it using the following code ( spring boot),

  ```
  GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
              JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                      .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(
                              "ID_CLIENT")
                      .build();
      try {
          GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(accessToken);
          if (idToken != null) {
              Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
              String userId = payload.getSubject();
              System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
              String email = payload.getEmail();
              boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
              String name = (String) payload.get("name");
              String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
              String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
              String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
              String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
              System.out.println(accessToken);
              return accessToken;
          } else {
              System.out.println("null");
              return "**this is not a valid Token**";
          }
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          return "IllegalArgumentException";
      }
  ```

  **it return** `IllegalArgumentException`

So how I can get **Google access token** using **Angular**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Angular 4, so there is no token variable there, unlike version 5 and 6,
so I follow [answer from this](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/10)

```
I solved this by going into node_modules/angular4-social-login and making a few changes.

First go into /entities and change the SocialUser model and include "token: string;" like so:
export declare class SocialUser {
provider: string;
id: string;
email: string;
name: string;
photoUrl: string;
token: string;
}

Go to angular4-social-login.umd.js and for every function of the GoogleLoginProvider where the SocialUser object is resolved - find "resolve(user)" - add the line:
user.token = _this.auth2.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token

Your authService should now return the idToken for the user as user.token.

(3) - for Facebook accessToken, you follow similiar logic. Go to angular4-social-login.umd.js; and for every FacebookLoginProvider function that resolves the user (again search for "resolve(user)"):
Under FB.login(function (response) {
//get the token here
var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken
...}

(4) Where the user is being modified, simply add user.token = accessToken before resolving ✨ ✨ ✨
```

> **------------------------>the token and authtoken are differents**